# GET form method wont append parameters

Tags: php, forms

I am working for a school project written in PHP for some weeks and i am stuck.

I am using for my structure a page index.php?page=.... where page could be home , game, aboutus,contact etc.

Now I am in `index.php?page=game` and I want to send using a form with GET method some parameters like game_name, created_by and stage_paused. Here comes the problem because when I press the Submit button I lose my `"page=game"` parameter and is something like `index.php?game_name=...&created_by=....`, and I don't have anymore my page=game, and by default my script check the page parameter and if not it renders the home page.

I checked w3 standards and they say that GET method shoud APPEND my form parameters with the one that is specified in the `action =""` on the form, but in my case I lose my page parameter.

I don't get it why it doesn't remember my current parameters when I submit the form.

I would appreciate very much your help and sorry for my bad english.

Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit HTML form with GET method with full action path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617592/submit-html-form-with-get-method-with-full-action-path) - You didn't check the w3 standards properly. It does not append get parameters, it removes all but takes them from the form inputs and takes the base URI (w/o the query-info part) from the action attribute only.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#submit-format - another possible duplicate: [Submitting form replaces constant GET information that is needed for the page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1558069/367456)

Answer (score 5):

Add the page parameter to either:

1. Your `<form>` action URL, or
2. Your `<form>` as a hidden `<input>` element, like so:

`<input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?= $_GET['page'] ?>" />`

Comment: Echoing a `$_GET` variable like that introduces a serious XSS vulnerability btw.

Answer (score 3):

A simple hidden input element should do the trick:

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $_GET['page']; ?>">
```

This way, the page parameter supplied via the URL is also considered as part of your form and therefore appended to the form action URL.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a hidden field for page:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="page" value="game" />
```

You could also change the form's method to POST and add the page to the action:

```
<form action="index.php?page=game" method="POST">
```